# How to use REGEX to capitalise the first letter of each word in a sentence?

Tags: regex

I would like to use regular expressions (REGEX) to capitalise the first letter of each word in a sentence.

I have achieved the same result in programming languages, but it seems that using regular expressions would be more concise.

Comment: How would you handle the case where you have an abbreviation?  Please provide a samples from the other languages you have done this in.

Comment: like "test testing" should return "Test Testing" im working on it with MSL and this code do exactly the same thing, but i know there is a way to use regex

alias reg {
  var %x = 1, %y = $$1, %z
  while (%x <= $numtok(%y,32)) {
    %z = %z $+($upper($left($gettok(%y,%x,32),1)),$mid($gettok(%y,%x,32),$iif($len($gettok(%y,%x,32)) == 1,$remove(%x,$right($gettok(%y,%x,32),1)),$+(-,$calc($len($gettok(%y,%x,32)) - 1))))) 
    inc %x
  }
  return %z
}

Comment: Also, which type of regex are you wanting to use? e.g. PCRE? POSIX?  There are subtle differences, and it makes a difference as to where and/or what languages you want to use the REGEX in.

Comment: Is that mirc scripting language?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Example using `sed` command.

```
~$ echo "foo bar" | sed  's/^\(.\)/\U\1/'
```

Where:

- the **`^`** represents the start of a line.
- **`.`** matches any character.
- **`\U`** converts to uppercase.
- `\( ... \)` specifies a section to be referenced later *(as `\1` in this case*).

Comment: i figured out that i can use 
/^(.)|(?<=\s)(.)/g or /\b(\S)/g but Thanks

Comment: `\U` - everything following in uppercase, `\u` next character only in uppercase

Comment: Can also be done with [vim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17440797/712526)